# FountainJs - Where do app.js and vendor.js gets generated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, yeoman-generator

Im kinda at loss here.

http://fountainjs.io/

Im using fountainJs for a project, using the following configurations:

- AngularJs 1.5
- Pure javascript
- Gulp
- SCC

The thing is, i have this project structure:

```
SRC
|- APP
  |-folder1
    |- file1.js
    |- file2.js
  |-folder2
    |- file3.js
    |- file4.js
|- common1.js


environment_variable='folder1'
```

And want that app.js only include JS files from one folder, defined by the environment variable (file1.js,file2.js), plus, the common ones (common1.js). Instead, every time i make a build, it includes all JS files uglified into the app.js, making all sort of conflicts.

Any ideas, or guides for me to use? I suspect that is the build.js file that makes all this, buy i dont understand what is going on there.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const filter = require('gulp-filter');
const useref = require('gulp-useref');
const lazypipe = require('lazypipe');
const rev = require('gulp-rev');
const revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const uglifySaveLicense = require('uglify-save-license');
const inject = require('gulp-inject');
const ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');

const conf = require('../conf/gulp.conf');

gulp.task('build', build);

function build() {
  const partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(conf.path.tmp('templateCacheHtml.js'), {read: false});
  const partialsInjectOptions = {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
    ignorePath: conf.paths.tmp,
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  const htmlFilter = filter(conf.path.tmp('*.html'), {restore: true});
  const jsFilter = filter(conf.path.tmp('**/*.js'), {restore: true});
  const cssFilter = filter(conf.path.tmp('**/*.css'), {restore: true});

  return gulp.src(conf.path.tmp('/index.html'))
    .pipe(inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
    .pipe(useref({}, lazypipe().pipe(sourcemaps.init, {loadMaps: true})))
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(uglify({preserveComments: uglifySaveLicense})).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
    .pipe(revReplace())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(htmlFilter)
    .pipe(htmlmin())
    .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.path.dist()))
        .pipe(gulp.src(conf.path.src('/templates/**/*')).pipe(gulp.dest(conf.path.dist('/templates'))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, you want to exclude js files from `folder2`.

To do so, you should exclude that path in the filter, you can use something like this:

```
const jsFilter = filter(
    conf.path.tmp(['**/*.js', '!folder2/*.js']), {restore: true}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having some problems with FountainJs. I started using it when the project already was mostly completed and so I had to make some compromises to make the build system fit the project.

Now the `build` task doesn't even create and `app.js` file. You could try to use `gulp-debug` to see which files are passed through the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Build script utilizes [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) to concatenate scripts and styles that injected into `index.html` using [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject). Both of the plugins search for special comments, [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) use:

- `<!-- bower:css -->`
- `<!-- inject:css -->`
- `<!-- bower:js -->`
- `<!-- inject:js -->`
- `<!-- inject:partials -->`

[gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) use:

- `<!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/vendor.css -->`
- `<!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->`
- `<!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->`
- `<!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->`

So everything need is mentioned in comments in `index.html`, you can refere to the plugins documentation to get details.

Also, you can take a look at [Angular-Gulp-Boilerplate](https://github.com/1oginov/Angular-Gulp-Boilerplate) that I forked long time ago and maintain to keep dependencies up to date and introduce new features since it is used in production project.